# PhpStorm - Undefined class FPDF

Tags: php, phpstorm, fpdf

I'm using FPDF for the first time, I get an 'Undefined class' error the origin of which I cant comprehend. Here is the relevant code:

```
<?php
    require_once("fpdf.php");
    require_once("Producto.php");
    session_start();

    $pdf = new FPDF();
```

As I said the last line throws Undefined class FPDF and for the life of me, I cannot figure out why, please help!

UPDATE: I think it has something to do with my version of PhpStorm, I get the same error when opening the premade tutorials, opened my file with NetBeans and haven't got the same error, will report back when I'm finished and let you know if the code works.

EDIT: Solved, had something to do with my PhpStorm, not entirely sure if it's due to the version but the same file worked as intended when opened with NetBeans, thanks everyone for your help. My PhpStorm version is(was) 2017.3.4

Comment: you have  FPDF class in  fpdf.php class ?

Comment: @Sona Yes, the file Im using is fpdf.php included here http://www.fpdf.org/es/dl.php?v=181&f=zip , as far as I can tell nothing in it is missing

Comment: what is the path for the current page what you have written ?

Comment: @Sona fpdf.php is situated in the same folder as the php file from which the code fragment comes from. Producto.php is in the same path and is working properly, which is why Im confused, should I post the entire code?

Comment: Do you have a namespace defined in your code file? If so, use `$pdf = new \FPDF();` instead. (prefix the class name with a backslash to tell PHP to look in the global namespace, rather than the current namespace)

Comment: Alternatively, if you have modified *fpdf.php* to have a specific namespace use the namespace for the initialization aswell. `$pdf = new Your\Name\Space\FPDF();`

Comment: @PhilippMaurer No namespace, havent modified fpdf.php either, will try using another class in the meantime if I can find it

Comment: IDE version (exactly)? 2018.1 (initial release) had issues with parsing huge files. Latest 2018.1.2 should parse them fine.

Comment: If the file is larger than 2Mb - it might not get parsed at all. If it's not  - make sure you're on latest IDE version